# Do I need to re-earn all the trophies to earn the platinum trophy from a new save game?

Tags: ps3, borderlands

I played Borderlands GOTY for quite some time and I was really close to the platinum trophy; I only needed to reach level 50.  But then the tragedy came and I lost my PS3 due to an electric shock and of course, all my saved games with it.

I was able to buy a new PS3, and start playing all over again. My question is, can I simply reach level 50 to obtain the platinum trophy, or do I have to obtain (or at least simulate obtaining) the rest of the trophies in order to gain the platinum?

Comment: I don't think you have to. The Platinum Trophy is awarded as soon as you unlock all non-DLC trophies. Unfortunately, I can't really back up my words; a similar situation happened to me, but I never managed to get the online trophies I needed to get Platinum.

Comment: @Nolonar I've been searching on google, but I've haven't been able to find someone in this situation. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to earn all the trophies in a single play-through to earn the platinum trophy.  As long as you've earned all the other (non-DLC) trophies on your account, you will earn the platinum trophy.

Comment: You know this from experience, or have you seen a similar situation?

Comment: @Chuck: Similar situation.  It's definitely not necessary to have save-games with the various trophies on the same machine *(or else you'd never know what else you need to get)*, and in a lot of games it's not even *posible* to get all the achievements in one playthrough!

Comment: Sounds logical, but I was reading some info about Diablo 3, and they said that the saved game was heavier that the XBOX version, since it save the trophy progress with your save. That's the main reason why I'm asking

Comment: @ChuckBirkini that x-box save could be for an achievement who's progress can't be carried though into multiple saves, an example of one (not Diablo) would be in a game where you can complete maps of places you've been to (like Final Fantasy XII or Final Fantasy XIII), however this map data isn't carried into a new game as such if there was an achievement require you to map every area this data would be record per save

Comment: @ChuckBirkin the Star Ocean The Last Hope Battle Trophies are stored in a separate location to the game save data thus allowing you to to start a new game and continue getting Battle Trophies you missed, this is in fact the only way to get all of Faize's and Arumat's Battle Trophies as the 2 can not be obtained be in the same party, this way the save game is smaller because it doesn't need to keep track of your battle trophies, a seperate file is used

Comment: Thanks for answering, it will take me some time to earn the last trophy, so for now I'll take it as solved. As soon as I have earn it, I'll let you know here.

Comment: @ChuckBirkin also 4 of the trophies involving using the unique skill of the 4 characters meaning you need at least 4 saves...thought i stopped trying to get platinum in Borderland GotY when one of the trophies either requires me to play with a Gearbox Software Employee of someone who has, so i just have 2 saves between the soldier and the siren so i have no idea if you can switch classes midgame (doubt it, never came across it even in DLC) as i tend to create a new game rather than doing New Game Plus data

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do all others. You can kick butt and still get the trophy when level 50.